# Extract bits from a byte array

Tags: javascript, arrays, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to make a function which extracts the bits from a byte array and returns decimal output from it.

```
function to_uint(x) {
    return x >>> 0;
}

function trunc(v){
    v = +v;
    if (!isFinite(v)) return v;
    return (v - v % 1)   ||   (v < 0 ? -0 : v === 0 ? v : 0);
}

function extract_bytes(chunk, startBit, endBit) {
    var totalBits = startBit - endBit + 1;
    var totalBytes = totalBits % 8 === 0 ? to_uint(totalBits / 8) : to_uint(totalBits / 8) + 1;
    var bitOffset = endBit % 8;
    var arr = new Array(totalBytes);
    for (var byte = totalBytes-1; byte >= 0; byte--) {
        var chunkIndex = byte + (chunk.length - 1 - trunc(startBit / 8));
        var lo = chunk[chunkIndex] >> bitOffset;
        var hi = 0;
        if (byte !== 0) {
            var hi_bitmask = (1 << bitOffset) - 1
            var bits_to_take_from_hi = 8 - bitOffset
            hi = (chunk[chunkIndex - 1] & (hi_bitmask << bits_to_take_from_hi));
        } else {
            lo = lo & ((1 << (totalBits % 8 ? totalBits % 8 : 8)) - 1);
        }
        arr[byte] = hi | lo;
    }
return arr;
}
```

These are the functions I'm using for this.

For example I will be calling it like so:

```
chunk = [0x0C, 0x47, 0x14, 0x76]
startBit = 1;
endBit = 0;
console.log(extract_bytes(chunk, startBit, endBit));
```

This functions works fine when the bits (start and end) for most cases. But when I try to read bits where the data is in two different bytes then it fails.
Here is a bit view of the chunk I will be using:

```
 //    0x0C      0x47      0x14      0x76
 //  [byte 0 ] [byte 1 ] [byte 2 ] [byte 3 ]
 //  0000 1100 0100 0111 0001 0100 0111 0110
```

For example:

```
chunk = [0x0C, 0x47, 0x14, 0x76]
startBit = 8
endBit = 0
```

This works and returns:

[ 0, 118 ]

Which means from byte3 (0x76) it exacted the whole thing ( index 7-0) and in byte2 (0x14) it extracted index 8.

But when I try:

```
chunk = [0x0C, 0x47, 0x14, 0x76]    
startBit = 11    
endBit = 6
```

it returns [0] instead of [17]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one :

```
function extract_bytes(chunk, startBit, endBit) {
    var arr = new Array(0);
    var word = 0x0;
    var wordCount = 0;
    var l = chunk.length;
    for (var i = startBit; i <= endBit; i++) {
        if (wordCount == 7) {
            arr.unshift(word);
            word = 0x0;
            wordCount = 0;
        }
        var work_ck =  parseInt((l*8 - 1 - i)/8,10);
        var bit_word_ck =  parseInt((l*8 - 1 - i) % 8,10);
        var next_bit = (chunk[work_ck] >> ( 7 - bit_word_ck)) & 0x1;
        word = word | (next_bit << 7);
        word = word >> 1;
        if (i != endBit) {
            wordCount += 1;
        }
    }

    if (wordCount != 0) {
        while (wordCount < 7) {
            word = word >> 1;
            wordCount += 1;
        }
        arr.unshift(word)
    }
    return arr;
}
```

It works for 2 of examples you explained; BUT you should invert startBit and endBit durring the call;

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The "===" and ">>>" are bitwise operations built into JS. I'm using the bitwise operations as this code gets called hundreds of times a second. I was thinking of using the string operations but it was much slower to run. The Start and endbit are included. So for example if I do startbit = 1 and endbit = 0. for lets say chunk 0x76. It will select the bits "10".

Comment: Let's check for awnser update.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It seems like this solution sort of works in these cases but break in other examples. Eg start = 7, end = 0 return [0, 118] instead of [118]. And start = 10, end = 0 returns [8, 118] instead of [4, 118]. Seems like a good base solution to work with.

Comment: Just try the updated code (without wordCount increment if i!= endBit).